# How can I add extra classes to the title of a node?

Tags: theming, nodes

I want to add more classes to the title of a node using the following code.

```
<h3{{ title_attributes.addClass(article-full__title) }}>{{ node.label }}</h3>
```

It doesn't work, despite the fact `title_attributes` is described as follows.

> title_attributes: Same as attributes, except applied to the main title tag that appears in the template.

I know that is possible to add classes straightly with code similar to the following one.

```
<h3 Class="article-full__title" }}>{{ node.label }}</h3>
```

I'm eager to know the standard way of doing this, and I don't want to miss anything.

My class names follow the [BEM Name Convention](https://en.bem.info/methodology/) rules and it's hard for me to break and behave contrary to those rules and change my class names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enclose the class in single quotes:

```
{{ title_attributes.addClass('article-full__title') }}
```

Otherwise this is interpreted as a variable name. In Twig unknown variables don't trigger an error, they return silently NULL.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, But is there any other way to solve this problem because my class names follow from [BEM Name Convention](https://en.bem.info/methodology/) and it's hard for me to breaking those rules and change my class names.

Comment: No, that's not the issue here, of course you can use BEM names. You only have to add the single quotes.